# Case always returns null?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, case

I have a subquery that gets the `DATEDIFF` of two dates. However the first `case` always returns `null` yet the actual sub query returns dates?!

```
CASE 
WHEN [date1] > [date2]
THEN DATEDIFF(DD,getdate(),date1) 
WHEN date1 < date2 
THEN DATEDIFF(DD,getdate(),date2) 
END[date diff]

FROM(

SELECT
licext.new_licenceId,
CASE 
WHEN CONVERT(time,licext.new_EmergencyLicenceExpiryDate) like '%23:00:00.000%'
THEN DATEADD(dd,1,CONVERT(date,licext.new_EmergencyLicenceExpiryDate))
ELSE CONVERT(date,licext.new_EmergencyLicenceExpiryDate)
END [date1], --EM Code

CASE 
WHEN CONVERT(time,licext.new_standardLicenceExpiryDate) like '%23:00:00.000%'
THEN DATEADD(dd,1,CONVERT(date,licext.new_standardLicenceExpiryDate))
ELSE CONVERT(date,licext.new_standardLicenceExpiryDate)
END [date2]  --FRL
from new_licenceExtensionBase licext
)QUERY
```

The reason the second cases are on there is because the database I am working with stores `datetime` in a really weird way, ie)If it has 23:00 at the end it actually means tomorrows date?! (This is a Microsoft CRM Database) -But that's a whole different matter.

EDIT:

It did have an ELSE clause which worked fine for date2 being bigger than date1, because that was being evaluated. For Example, the following code works fine for getting the difference between today and date2:

```
CASE 
WHEN [date1] > [date2]
THEN DATEDIFF(DD,getdate(),date1) 
ELSE DATEDIFF(DD,getdate(),date2) 
END[date diff]
```

EDIT 2:

I've just done a couple of tests:
Using a select to return the dates works fine. -They return as expected.

Test 2: I've added a third `WHEN` to the query to say that when a date is null, return 1990-01-01..However it still returns `null`, Is my whole case being skipped over?

Comment: There is only one explanation for a time of "11:00 pm" being really tomorrow's date - your time-zone is set incorrectly somewhere. Times (and consequently date-times)should always be stored as UTC (or ZULU-time for the dinosaurs) at the server and converted to local time by the client. This is what is broken, not the MS software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `ELSE` in your first `CASE`, which means if none of your `WHEN` expressions are matched then it returns `NULL`.

My guess is there's an issue in your logic below that causes `date1` and `date2` to always be equal, which would miss both your `WHEN`s in the first `CASE` and return `NULL`.

Comment: Sorry, see my update.

Comment: @KidCode That still doesn't cover the possibility of the dates being EQUAL, which is what is happening. Both your date columns use the same calc so they will have the same value.

Comment: But they don't use the same calculations? They use two totally different columns. I can pretty much guarantee they aren't equal either. Because date1 has 3 values,(the rest being Null) non of which are in date2.(Date2 isn't null)

Am I missing something? -Sorry :(

Comment: Sorry I missed the column name changes in all that code :) Output the raw dates in a select to see what you get.

Comment: If `date1` is equal to `date2` or if `date1` is null or if `date2` is null, then the `CASE` expression result will be `NULL`, just as @JNK answered.

Comment: Also, when you tried printing the dates, did you print `date1` and `date2` or the `licext.new_standardLicenceExpiryDate` and `icext.new_EmergencyLicenceExpiryDate` values?